# How to use Wolfram language in an external program with low latency?

Tags: compile, mathlink-or-wstp, raspberry-pi

Im using Wolfram language on Pi B,and I want to compile a '.m' file (like "test.m" that contains Wolfram functions), in an external program like a C/C++ and then Export the output in an image file type.

I have made these efforts:

1-I used `wolfram -script test.m` to compile test.m and it worked but it was too slow for me.

2-I used Wolfram headers like (libML32i3.a ,libML32i3.so ,libML32i4.a ,libML32i4.so ,mathlink.h) and copied them in "/usr/include" directory then as what [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WSTPDeveloperGuide-Unix.html#4756) said (WSTP Development in C) I compiled one of the C codes in MathLink for examples by "make", the problem was when I wanted to run any of those codes like `./factor` then I was asked for "Create link:" and then I typed something for example 'a' after that the program asked me "Integer to factor:" and when I typed the number the program couldn't display the output.(for example it takes 5 minutes but the program still doesn't have output).

3-I also used `mkfifo mmpipe`,`tail -f mmpipe | wolfram`,and then `echo Export["test.gif", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]] > mmpipe"` and wolfram displayed an error `"Export::chtype: First argument test . gif is not a valid file specification."`

so what should I do now.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, format your code accordingly -- either go to the help centre or press the curly bracket button directly in the text editor